# Rails: Making User's Micropost show on another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, microblogging

I have a User model that can post microblogs and it shows up on the user show page but I was wondering how would I be able to show the user made microblogs onto a model that the user belongs to for instance in this case a school. Users belong to specific schools and the schools have many users under them. All help much appreciated!

**User Show Page**

```
<div id="MicropostBody">
 <div>
 <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
    <table class="microposts">
      <%= render @microposts %>
    </table>
    <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
 <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

**School Show Page** 
Same thing?

```
<div id="MicropostBody">
 <div>
 <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
    <table class="microposts">
      <%= render @microposts %>
    </table>
    <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
 <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

**User Controller**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @school = School.find(params[:id])
  @micropost = Micropost.new
  @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

**School Controller**
Same thing??

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @school = School.find(params[:id])
  @micropost = Micropost.new
  @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

**New School Controller**

```
def show
  @school = School.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.new
  @micropost = Micropost.new
  @microposts = @school.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @micropost = current_school.microposts.build
end
```

Comment: You need to take a look at [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Comment: @Bradley Thanks Bradley, you been helping me a lot with my questions lately haha, mmm do you think you can lend me a little more hand on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look back at the [partials](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout?version=3.2#sec%3apartials) section of the Rails tutorial book before reading any further, if you're still struggling.

`users/_microposts.html.erb`

```
<div id="MicropostBody">
  <div>
    <% if microposts.any? %>
      <table class="microposts">
        <%= render microposts %>
      </table>
      <%= will_paginate microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in both views you can use:

`<%= render 'users/microposts', :microposts => @microposts %>`

Comment: The rendering partials helped thanks Bradley but this is what really changed it, I updated the code!